# Continue executing once any of multiple promises are completed (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm writing a typescript discord bot right now, but none of this question has to do with typescript or discord.js. I'll explain it using the reference of a bot however:

I have a bot that needs to fire a few commands once a user either clicks a reaction OR sends "I agree" in the chat. Once either one of those is true, the next commands should execute. Here's some background information:

```js
//We already have two functions that we can await for each event (clicks checkmark or responds)
//We can use them using await, because we are in an async function

async function run(){

await clickCheckmark() || respond()
send('hi');
}
```

This syntax doesnt work, but is there any that does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Promise.race()`, which takes an array of promises and returns a promise that resolves or rejects with whichever one goes off first:

```
async function run() {
    await Promise.race([clickCheckmark(), respond()]);
    send('hi');
}
```